# Automate the process to construct LinkedList

Tags: python

I have such a LinkedList

> Given linked list: 1->2->3->4->5,

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

Then have to built the LinkedList manually.

```
    head = ListNode(1)
    node1 = ListNode(2)
    node2 = ListNode(3)
    node3 = ListNode(4)
    node4 = ListNode(5)
    head.next = node1
    node1.next = node2
    node2.next = node3
    node3.next = node4
    node4.next = None
```

Is it possible to automate the process, something like

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    node(i-1) = ListNode(i) #made up the node(i-1)
```

Comment: You could do `node = [ListNode(i) for i in range(1, 6)]`, and then refer to `node[1]`, `node[2]`, etc., but having your linked list nodes in an actual list makes your linked list kind of redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert a iterables such as `list` into LinkedList by that:

```
def generate_linked_list(nums):
    cur = dummy = ListNode(0)
    for num in nums:
        cur.next = ListNode(num)
        cur = cur.next
    return dummy.next
```

`dummy` node is used for the case that `nums` is empty.

or a trick way use `self` without use `dummy` node, if it is a class function:

```
class LinkedList:
    def generate_linked_list(self, nums):
        cur = self
        for num in nums:
            cur.next = ListNode(num)
            cur = cur.next
        return self.next
```

Usage:

```
head = generate_linked_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Appreciate deeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeply for your tutorial.